# How to compare time complexities involving an exponential and a polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, algorithms, computer-science

A sequence of events $A_n, n \in \mathbb{N}$ is said to have a high probability, if $\mathrm{P} (A_n^c) \leq \frac{c}{n^d}$ for some $c, d >0$.

Chernoff bounds are often used to prove some (upper or lower) tail events of a binomial distributed random variable $X$ have a high probability.
In such proofs, we are given a function $f$, and often need to find some $a, b>0$, such that $e^{f(n)}   \leq \frac{a}{n^b}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

For example,

1. $$ e^{-\frac{10 \ln n}{2} \ln(10 \ln n)} \leq \frac{1}{n^8}, \text{
       for every } n \geq 2 $$ and $$ e^{-\frac{9 \ln n \ln 9}{2} } \leq
       \frac{1}{n^8}. $$ How are the exponents $8$ of $\frac{1}{n^8}$
   determined in the above two examples?
2. Is it possible to determine the constants $c, a, b$ for each of the following two
   examples, $$ e^{- \frac{(c \ln n -\frac{\ln n}{n^2} + 1) * \ln (cn^2
       + \frac{n^2}{\ln n}-1)}{2}}  \leq \frac{a}{n^b}, $$ and $$ e^{- (c \ln n + 1) * \ln (c\ln n+1) }  \leq \frac{a}{n^b}? $$
3. Does the LHS of each above example belong to the sub-exponential
   time complexity?

Thanks!

Comment: In the second example under 1., since

$$
\mathrm e^{-9\ln n\ln 9/2}=n^{-9\ln 9/2}\approx n^{-9.9}\;,
$$

the exponent $8$ is somewhat arbitrary and not very tight.

Comment: What is the meaning of the exponent $c$ in $P(A_n^c)$?

Comment: @Peter: "c" means complement of set.

Answer (score 1):

1) Try the simple derivation
$$e^{(-9\ln n \ln 9)/2} = n^{-4.5\ln 9} \le n^{-8}.$$
You could have also used a somewhat smaller constant instead of $-8$, but it's irrelevant if all you want is *high probability* for this event.

2) Same as in 1). Just use algebra to simplify the LHS and bring it into the form of the RHS. That will determine the constants $a$ and $b$.

3) The LHS goes to $0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$ so it clearly is sub-exponential, in fact it's in $o(1)$.